# How to monitor extension/addon requests?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

There is an existing extension (both for Firefox and Chrome) that receives fresh information from a server every minute.

How to analyze how that extension works? I.e. monitor/intercept requests and responses made by it.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unreadable in English. _Your name sounds Russian, if you can - post the question in Russian in a comment, I'll translate for you._

Comment: Есть расширение для бразуера firefox которое обменивается даннимы из сервером, мне нужно отследить куда посылает запросы расшрирение и какие получает ответы З.Ы. Спасибо Xan

Comment: Хм. Вопрос всё равно непонятен. Вы пытаетесь это понять про расширение, которое писали не вы? Из браузера, или с сервера?

Comment: Я не писал это расширение. моя задача понять как он обменивается иноформаций из сервером. Какждую минуту от сервера он получает новые данные, я не понимаю от куда и как  он их получает.

Comment: Edited the question according to the discussion in comments.

Comment: Plus rep to Xan for being awesome for translating someones text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Chrome-specific answer

You can monitor all network traffic from an extension with the usual Dev Tools even if it's a "production" extension and not a locally-loaded development version.

Requests made by the extension can be monitored just like any other page. From `chrome://extensions/` with Developer Mode enabled, you should be able to inspect the background page of the extension in question, which will open Dev Tools. If you switch to **Network** tab, you will see all requests made by the background page, which is the most likely source of such requests, together with server replies.

Since Chrome 20, this even [logs WebSocket traffic](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/), though packets exchanged will be appended to the log event that established the connection, not create new entries. You might not see that log entry if you attached Dev Tools later than page load. If you suspect you're missing WebTools traffic for a background page, open Dev Tools and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page (effectively restarting the extension) without closing Dev Tools.

It is possible that some other part of the extension makes those requests, for instance a content script running in a normal tab. Then, you need to examine the tab's Dev Tools' Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you can use the Browser Console / Network Tab. (Acess with Ctrl + Shift + J (or on mac Command + Shift + J)). Or you can download addons like [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)